# How to configure different types of deployment to ECS using Terraform

Tags: terraform

How do I do rolling update , Bluegreen, replace deployment types using terraform for ECS task deployment?

I do not see such option under aws_ecs_service resoruce.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use code deploy with ecs service to manage your deployments, here an module for this, see this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hendrixroa/ecs-service-blue-green-deployment/aws/latest)

Comment: Thanks you please let me know how to do a rolling deployment and replace deployment through terraform

Comment: Check this link https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hendrixroa/ecs-service-blue-green-deployment/aws/latest

Comment: It looks like it is using codedeploy. I would like to avoide that. I would like to use a third party pipeline for deployments